# Netlogo - selecting all turtles at a given distance from a special agent

Tags: netlogo

I have to select and compute the nearest turtle from a fixed point, however i want the distance to be changeable, in the sense that i have a slider and i want to select the nearest turtle with that 
 given distance from that point.
I've tried many solution, also with the `in-radius` function, but it does not produce the desired output.
Can anyone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Enrico! Your title says that you want **all turtles** within (?) a given distance from the agent (in which case `in-radius` would be the right primitive to use) but the text of your question says you want **the nearest turtle** (in which case something like `turtles with-min [ distance myself ]` might be what you need). Can you clarify what you mean? Also, it always helps to be explicit about what you tried and what result you got. Just saying that you tried `in-radius` but it didn't work isn't quite sufficient for us to help you.

Comment: I'm sorry but this was my first post, thanks for your quick reply.
The fact is that I have a fixed turtle that represent a stage, and there are seats that are orientated towards it.
Every time a person wants to find a seat, he needs to find a free seat that is the nearest seat from the stage but with a given distance from other seats that are occupied, so a sort of repulsion expressed with the distance.
I hope that I was clear this time, thanks in advance, Enrico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enrico, I don't have enough reputation points to comment so I'll post this as an answer.  Your question was two weeks ago and you may no longer need an answer.

If the discussion below correctly describes your problem, as well as the generic logic involved in it,  you should have enough to be able to write the basic NetLogo model, or to get the basic control structures written and focus on the specific point where you can't figure out the NetLogo syntax to implement the desired functionality.  Or perhaps you have code already in place and we just haven't seen it here.

At that point, the wonderful StackOverflow members should be able to help you answer specific questions in a shared context and understanding of what you're trying to do, what code you are using, and what happens when you try to run the model.

Is the following a correct restatement of your problem?

**The Situation**

The situation is a stage in a theater with multiple rows of seats.  People come in one at a time and are always seated in the row nearest the stage that still has at least one empty seat. When that row is full, seating begins in the next row further away from the stage.   When all rows are filled, the simulation stops.  Within a row that has more than one empty seat, a seat is chosen that is maximizes some measure of collective distance from other seated people, including possibly people in other rows.

Question -- is the theater rectangular with linear rows of seats, or circular with concentric circular rows of seats around the stage?

**Design Considerations**

The collective-distance-metric calculation can be put into a separate routine and doesn't affect the rest of a basic NetLogo model setup.

Some possible metrics might be:
1)  maximize the distance to the nearest seated person in the same row
2)  maximize the distance to the nearest seated person in the entire theater
3)  maximize the sum of distances to everyone seated in the same row
4)  maximize the sum of distances to everyone seated in the entire theater
5)  maximize the square root of the sum of squares of distance to everyone
*  in the theater who smokes cigars.

Regardless of choice of metric, we will logically always do the same thing:

- Pick initial seating arrangement and possibly initial seated persons
- Pick the row to work on next

Loop

- Pick which row to work on next, or exit if all rows are full
- For each empty seat in that row
- Find the agent-set of filled-seats that are relevant to the calculation
- ( say, filled-seats in the same row as the empty seat )
- For that agent-set, compute the collective-distance-metric
- Then pick the empty seat which generated the maximum collective-distance-metric
- Sit there
- update global statistics as desired
- display statistics as desired

end-loop

**NetLogo Implementation**

Do what you can and come back with it here.

You might want to make people and seats two different breeds of turtles.  You can layout all the seats in "setup" and then add people as you go.

Seats could own variables "row" and "occupied?" It's easy to layout circular rings of turtles using the "layout-circle" function.  Maybe make unoccupied seats green circles of size 2, and change them to red when they become occupied.